# GridSearch paramgrid

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to use k-fold cross validation on a linear regression model but I want to leave out 1 parameter from the model each time. For example: If the model has 3 variables, then I'd want `ab,ac,bc` where `a`,`b`,and `c` are dependent variables. I'm not sure how to use `param_grid` to do this.

If there are 10 variables, is it simply:

`param_grid={'a':[1,10]}`?

---

I have looked at the documentation but they seem to assume I have a familarity with the function...

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding grid search. Grid search applies to hyperparameters, which aren't directly learned from the models. Linear regression models don't have hyperparameters, though in the case of sklearn, it would be the parameters in the class constructor, (e.g. `fit_intercept`, `normalize`). If you want to leave a variable out in your modeling, then you would remove the variable column out of your dataset.

Comment: there is no better way?

Comment: There is no better way, though I question why you would want to leave one variable out. If your aim is to determine what variables would be important, you should take a look at sklearn's [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  @Scratch'N'Purr has made it clear, this implementation is not available with scikit-learn yet.

**Option 1**
Implement your own -

```
from __future__ import print_function

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
print(__doc__)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# Split the dataset in two equal parts
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df[['A', 'B', 'C']], df['D'], test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

n_features = X_train.shape[1]
subsets = []
feature_lst = range(3) # truncating to keep it small
for i in range(2, len(feature_lst)+1):
    #subsets.append(i)
    subsets += [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(feature_lst, i)]
print(subsets)

best_score = -np.inf
best_subset = None
lreg = LinearRegression()
for subset in subsets:
    lreg.fit(X_train.iloc[:, subset], y_train)
    print(lreg.score(X_test.iloc[:, subset], y_test))
```

**Output**

This fit a linear regression model for each combination of features. Here is the output -

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
-0.173503748866
-0.069322067281
-0.159670591221
-0.173960013649
```

Notice how its giving you the combination of the features used and the corresponsing `R squared` values.'

**Option 2**
Use scikit-learn's [LARS](http://scikitlearn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) implementation that does `stepwise` regression -

```
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> reg = linear_model.LassoLars(alpha=.1)
>>> reg.fit([[0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, 1])  
LassoLars(alpha=0.1, copy_X=True, eps=..., fit_intercept=True,
     fit_path=True, max_iter=500, normalize=True, positive=False,
     precompute='auto', verbose=False)
>>> reg.coef_    
array([ 0.717157...,  0.        ])
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!